# Basketball FT continuation to closed question

Tags: probability

Here's the question:

> A certain basketball player practices shooting free throws over and over
> again. The shots are independent, with probability p of success.
>
> - **(b)** Now suppose that the player keeps shooting until making $7$ shots in a row for the first time. Let $X$ be the number of shots taken. Show that $E(X) ≤ \frac{7}{p^7}.$ (Note that, for example, $9$ in a row counts as $3$ streaks.)

I was thinking about this with linearity of expectation and Geometric distributions, but an answer on a closed question seems to disagree with my answer, and I was wondering if someone could explain the discrepancy.

My solution:

$I_i$ is if the $i$th group of 7 throws has all heads. $X$ is the group number of 7 throws of the first time all 7 are makes; $X \sim \text{FS}(p^7)$. $E(X) = \frac{1}{p^7}$. $Y$ is the number of shots until 7 makes. $Y = X + 6$. $E(Y) = E(X) + 6 = 6 + \frac{1}{p^7}$. It is obvious that $6 + \frac{1}{p^7} \leq \frac{7}{p^7}$ with some simple algebra.

The other solution:

> $E(n)$ be the expected number of shots taken until $n$ shots are made
> in a row. We have the following recursive relationship: $$E(n) = E(n-1) + p + (1-p)(1+E(n)).$$ Simplifying this, we get: $$E(n) = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{E(n-1)}{p}$$ Knowing $E(0) = 0$, we can prove that
> $E(7) = \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{p^3}+\frac{1}{p^4}+\frac{1}{p^5}+\frac{1}{p^6}+\frac{1}{p^7}\leq \frac{7}{p^7}.$

Clearly, my solution of $6 + \frac{1}{p^7} \neq \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{1}{p^3}+\frac{1}{p^4}+\frac{1}{p^5}+\frac{1}{p^6}+\frac{1}{p^7}$ generally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's some confusion with $$X \sim FS(p^7)$$. The $FS$ distribution assumes independent trials. Here the trials are not independent. E.g. Let $A = \{\text{shots 1 through 7 are successful}\}$ and $B = \{\text{shots 2 through 8 are successful}\}$. $A$ and $B$ are not independent.